# unable to resolve module `@expo/vector-icons`

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

Im not sure why I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to resolve module `@expo/vector-icons` from `...(directory path here)...` : Module does not exist in the module pack
```

I have tried the following things suggested on other forums/sites:

1. Clear watchman watches
2. Deleting the node_modules folder
3. Reset packager cache

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Hello Expo!",
  "author": null,
  "private": true,
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^2.5.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^4.0.0",
    "expo": "^21.0.0",
    "firebase": "^4.5.1",
    "geofire": "^4.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-21.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.13"
  }
}
```

But still nothing, still getting this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like `vector-icons` is another library you should be declaring in your `package.json` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@expo/vector-icons)

Answer (score 8):

I resolved the issue by this command `npm install @expo/vector-icons --save`

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue. It's the babel-preset-expo. uninstall that and do the following

```
npm i metro-react-native-babel-preset --save-dev
```

delete the babel.config.json and create a new file called .babelrc

then specify the preset

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

Comment: This was necessary for me after ejecting my expo app. Even after I changed all of the imports from `@expo/vector-icons` to 'react-native-vector-icons` and clearing all of the caches and build data, I was still getting this error. Changing the babel preset fixed the problem.

Comment: is it (.babelrc) only the extension? Can you share all the codes in .babelrc please

Comment: Hey @Exceptionhandler, that's all I have in my .babelrc. That is the whole filename too.

Answer (score 3):

Command `npm install @expo/vector-icons --save` do the trick !

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I had this error, was because when I put `useState` in my app, VS Code auto imported it from `react-native-vector-icons/node_modules/@types/react`, instead of from "react"

Answer (score 0):

`rm -rf node_modules` then `npm install` helped me.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install @expo/vector-icons --save` or `yarn add @expo/vector-icons --save`
worked for me

If that doesn't work then try going into `package.json` and manually deleting `@expo/vector-icons` then type the command above again.